# grep and regrex for R phone numbers

Tags: r, regex

I would like to get the phone numbers from a file. I know the numbers have different forms, I don't know how to code for each form. Using grep and regrexpr in R. The numbers are written in this form:

xxx-xxx-xxxx ,
(xxx)xxx-xxxx, 
xxx xxx xxxx, 
 xxx.xxx.xxxx

Comment: What have you tried? Those four patterns could be matched by `grepl("^(\\(\\d{3}\\)|\\d{3}[-. ])\\d{3}[-. ]\\d{4}$", phones)`. What do you want to do with them? Are they always complete strings, or embedded among other things?

Comment: it spits out falso for me, they are complete strings but start on a separate line and on some lines there is a word i.e: 
food
888-888-8888
cat
777.777.7777

Comment: It spit out false because you did not really get into requirements of the extraction. For example, the comment-code works fine given an assumption that the potential numbers are whole-strings, not substrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```r
phones <- c("foo 111-111-1111 bar" , "(111)111-1111 quux", "who knows 111 111 1111", "111.111.1111 I do", "111)111-1111 should not work", "1111111111 ditto", "a 111-111-1111 b (222)222-2222 c")
re <- gregexpr("(\\(\\d{3}\\)|\\d{3}[-. ])\\d{3}[-. ]\\d{4}", phones)
regmatches(phones, re)
# [[1]]
# [1] "111-111-1111"
# [[2]]
# [1] "(111)111-1111"
# [[3]]
# [1] "111 111 1111"
# [[4]]
# [1] "111.111.1111"
# [[5]]
# character(0)
# [[6]]
# character(0)
# [[7]]
# [1] "111-111-1111"  "(222)222-2222"
```

In the data, I provide a few examples with other text on both, either, and neither side, as well as two examples that should not match. (That is: a starter "test set", as you want to make sure you both match good examples and no-match bad examples.) The last one hopes to match multiple numbers in one string/sentence.

`gregexpr` and `regmatches` are useful for finding and extracting or replacing regex-substrings within 1+ strings. For a "replace" example, one could do:

```r
regmatches(phones, re) <- "GONE!"
phones
# [1] "foo GONE! bar"                "GONE! quux"                  
# [3] "who knows GONE!"              "GONE! I do"                  
# [5] "111)111-1111 should not work" "1111111111 ditto"            
# [7] "a GONE! b GONE! c"
```

Obviously contrived replacement but certainly usable. Note though that `regmatches` operates in *side-effect*, meaning that it modified the `phones` vector in-place instead of returning the value. It's possible to force it to operate *not* in side-effect, but it is a little less intuitive:

```r
phones # I reset it to the original value
# [1] "foo 111-111-1111 bar"             "(111)111-1111 quux"              
# [3] "who knows 111 111 1111"           "111.111.1111 I do"               
# [5] "111)111-1111 should not work"     "1111111111 ditto"                
# [7] "a 111-111-1111 b (222)222-2222 c"
`regmatches<-`(phones, re, value = "GONE!")
# [1] "foo GONE! bar"                "GONE! quux"                  
# [3] "who knows GONE!"              "GONE! I do"                  
# [5] "111)111-1111 should not work" "1111111111 ditto"            
# [7] "a GONE! b GONE! c"           
phones
# [1] "foo 111-111-1111 bar"             "(111)111-1111 quux"              
# [3] "who knows 111 111 1111"           "111.111.1111 I do"               
# [5] "111)111-1111 should not work"     "1111111111 ditto"                
# [7] "a 111-111-1111 b (222)222-2222 c"
```

---

**Edit**: scope-creep.

```r
out <- unlist(Filter(length, regmatches(phones, re)))
out
# [1] "111-111-1111"  "(111)111-1111" "111 111 1111"  "111.111.1111"  "111-111-1111" 
# [6] "(222)222-2222"
gsub("[^0-9]", "", out)
# [1] "1111111111" "1111111111" "1111111111" "1111111111" "1111111111" "2222222222"
out <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", out)
sprintf("(%s)%s-%s", substr(out, 1, 3), substr(out, 4, 6), substr(out, 7, 10))
# [1] "(111)111-1111" "(111)111-1111" "(111)111-1111" "(111)111-1111" "(111)111-1111"
# [6] "(222)222-2222"
```

Comment: but I am extracting from a txt file, would I have to make my txt file a vector than?

Comment: If you want R to do it, you have to read it in with something like `readLines`. It has to be read into memory by *something* to be done, so if it is too large for R, then find something else (suggestions: `sed` or `python`). Have you tried `phones <- readLines("path/to/file.txt")` and then do the above?

Comment: yes got it thanks! but if I just want it to print the numbers as above without printing the character(0) as seen above in your example, would I use a different function?

Comment: one more question: I did this:
 re <- gregexpr("(\\(\\d{3}\\)|\\d{3}[-. ])\\d{3}[-. ]\\d{4}", phones)
Filter(length, regmatches(phones, re))

however it is not printing the numbers in the form (###) ###-###

Comment: (1) Are you storing the results from `Filter(...)`? You should. (2) It would have been magical had it done it that way, since you never stated that as a "requirement".

Comment: yes, it is stored, is it possible it is missing a space (\\s in the code), because the number is written as (###) ###-####  there's a space between the ) and #?

Comment: `"(\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s?|\\d{3}[-. ])\\d{3}[-. ]\\d{4}"` (your example had no spaces, please be careful in your questions to include accurate sample data and requirements)